# Implementing proper validation for enumerated objects in Automapper

Tags: c#, automapper

I have an object(DTO) of type *T* that contains an **IList** of objects *T1* and so on that have the following stucture:

```
public class T
{
    public IList<T1> SubGroup { get; set; }
}
public class T1
{
    public IList<T2> SubGroup { get; set; }
}
public class T2
{
    public IList<T3> SubGroup { get; set; }
}
public class T3
{
    public int Order{ get; set; }
    public string Data {get; set; }
}
```

I want to be able to do some validations when an object of type *T* is received based on the *order* attribute, more specifically:

- Make sure that the order is persistent for the whole range of objects, eg (1,2,3,4,5) and not (1,3,4,5)
- Make sure that there are no duplicates, eg (1,2,2,3,4,5) should not be allowed.

I have very basic notion of **Automapper** and it seems like a "sophisticated" question, is there a way to achieve that in an easy way(instead of writing a "mapper like" utility class)?

Comment: That should not be the concern of the mapper. It's also unclear if that's for one instance of T2 or over the entire Tree structure?

Comment: @Fildor Hi and thank you for your repsonse, Well, I am referring to all the objects, we are essentially talking about a controller that needs to convert an incoming DTO to a DBO, so it will iterate over all the instances of the lists(there are some other trivial attributes in most of the objects but it is fine for them since they have the same type and name in both the DTO and DBO).

Comment: Since you mentioned that this should not be a concern of the mapper, should it be checked on the repository level? In general we are talking about an asp net application

Comment: I would have it validated on the dtos as soon as possible. The earlier you detect a request error, the less unneccessary work on your server is done. "Fail early".

Comment: @Fildor would you mind giving an example? Should I create a constructor for the DTOs that throws when a validation error occurs? It feels like the only checking thats happening is at the automapper level

Comment: DTOs come in at your Controller, right? So, here you can either have some middleware for DTO validation (look at FluentValidation) or you do it manually with custom code. _Before_ mapping - which you want to avoid performing on invalid input.

Comment: I got it! Thank you very much!